# Open multiple files using fileopendlg() function

Tags: mapbasic

I want to open multiple files using `fileopendlg()` function, when I code it selects only one file at a time. Is there any function or procedure to select multiple files at a time?

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @RajeshDeswal! Perhaps this link might help: [MapBasic: using a method from a .NET assembly (OpenFileDialog)](http://twiav-tt.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/mapbasic-using-method-from-net-assembly.html).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, MapBasic does not provide the means to open multiple files through the `FileOpenDlg` function. However, as described in the link posted by Joseph in the comments, you can use a .NET assembly to give you that functionality. A few years back I wrote an assembly to handle a bunch of file and folder functions, including a multi-file version of the FileOpenDlg, and uploaded it to the community downloads site including code examples on how to use it. You can find it [here](http://communitydownloads.pbinsight.com/code-exchange/download/file-folder-and-drive-functions-library/). You may find some of the other functions it provides useful as well!